# How to show table border in CKeditor

Tags: angular, angular6, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using CKEditor to write some text with tables on one page(Page A) and then send it to another page(Page B), the editor works fine when I'm editing my text and the table shows, but when I retrive my text (with editor.getData() ) and send it to Page B, the table dissapears

The text retrieved with editor.getData() is for example

```
<table><tableRow><tableCell><paragraph>Foo</paragraph></tableCell><tableCell><paragraph>Bar</paragraph></tableCell></tableRow></table>
```

and this shows a "borderless" table in (Page B), (Page B) does show a table when it's formatted this way

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">This is a table </table>
```

I configured my CKeditor like this:

// Plugins to include in the build.

```
ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [
    Essentials,
    UploadAdapter,
    Autoformat,
    BlockQuote,
    CKFinder,
    Heading,
    Link,
    List,
    MediaEmbed,
    Paragraph,
    PasteFromOffice,
    Table,
    TableToolbar,
];

// Editor configuration.
ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'bold', 'italic', 'insertTable'
        ]
    },
    table: {
        contentToolbar: [
            'tableColumn',
            'tableRow',
            'mergeTableCells'
        ]
    },
    indentBlock: {
        offset: 1,
        unit: 'em'
    },
    language: 'en'
};
```

Did I forget something in my config in order to show table style(a table with a visible border for example)?

Answer (score 0):

CK Editor CSS will not load on Page B, it is upto developer to add CSS on generated content.
Try adding this CSS on page B.

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Reference](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#what-happened-to-the-contentscss-file-how-do-i-style-the-content-of-the-editor)